# Python program to calculate student grades

Tags: python

This is my first program in Python and I am having some trouble so forgive me if I have some simply syntax issues.

I am writing a program that calculates a student's final score based on one exam grade worth 60% and 7 other test scores worth a combined 40% of the final grade. The user is asked to input the one exam score then asked to input the 7 test scores which are read in a loop. The letter grade is then determined from the final score calculated from the exam and tests. After that a grade comment is printed corresponding to the letter grade given to the student. This is my code so far:

```
def read_test_scores() :

    print("ENTER STUDENT ID: ")
    id = int(input())

    print("ENTER EXAM SCORE: ")
    exam = int(input())

    print("ENTER ALL TEST SCORES: ")
    score1 = int(input())
    score2 = int(input())
    score3 = int(input())
    score4 = int(input())
    score5 = int(input())
    score6 = int(input())
    score7 = int(input())

    sum = (score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 + score6 + score7)

    tavge = sum/7
    return tavge

def compute_final_score(tavge, exam) :
    final_score = 0.4 * tavge + 0.6 * exam
    return final_score

def get_letter_grade(final_score) :

    if 90 <= final_score <= 100:
        grade = 'A'
    elif 80 <= final_score <= 89:
        grade = 'B'
    elif 70 <= final_score <= 79:
        grade = 'C'
    elif 60 <= final_score <= 69:
        grade = 'D'
    else:
        grade = 'F'
    return grade

def print_comment(grade) :

    if grade = 'A':
        print "COMMENT:            Very Good"
    elif grade = 'B':
        print "COMMENT:            Good"
    elif grade = 'C':
        print "COMMENT:            Satisfactory"
    elif grade = 'D':
        print "COMMENT:            Need Improvement"
    elif grade = 'F'
        print "COMMENT:            Poor"

read_test_scores()
print "TEST AVERAGE IS:    " + str(tavge)
compute_final_score()
print "FINAL SCORE IS:     " + str(final_score)
get_letter_grade(final_score)
print "LETTER GRADE IS:     " + str(grade)
print_comment(grade)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble is not a question. [ask]

Comment: What is the question? Be specific. Also the first sentence is not necessary, just state the question.

Comment: My program is not running. One issue is with syntax in print_comment function specifically  "if grade = 'A'. I have no experience with Python so me reading over my code over and over does nothing. I need someone with experience to look over and help find any obvious errors please.

Comment: That's still not a question.

Comment: `=` is for assignment, instead do comparisons with `==`, `if grade == 'A':`

Comment: Speaking of assignment, you need to assign the result of the function calls to variables, and pass those variables as arguments to the next function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my answer.  The code should run.  Notes are inserted as comments.

```
# NOTE: I haven't checked whether your math is right, or
# if the computed values are correct.  I did however get your
# script to work.


def read_test_scores():
    print("ENTER STUDENT ID: ")
    id = int(input())

    print("ENTER EXAM SCORE: ")
    exam = int(input())

    print("ENTER ALL TEST SCORES: ")
    score1 = int(input())
    score2 = int(input())
    score3 = int(input())
    score4 = int(input())
    score5 = int(input())
    score6 = int(input())
    score7 = int(input())

    sum = (score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 + score6 + score7)

    tavge = sum / 7.0

    # NOTE: if you want to use any variables from this function,
    # then you have to "bring them outside" by "returning"
    # them. Here, I return the values tavge, id, and exam. I noticed
    # that bringing out "exam" is necessary since you'll
    # be using it later on.
    return tavge, id, exam


def compute_final_score(tavge, exam):
    final_score = 0.4 * tavge + 0.6 * exam
    return final_score


def get_letter_grade(final_score):
    if 90 <= final_score <= 100:
        grade = 'A'
    elif 80 <= final_score <= 89:
        grade = 'B'
    elif 70 <= final_score <= 79:
        grade = 'C'
    elif 60 <= final_score <= 69:
        grade = 'D'
    else:
        grade = 'F'
    return grade


def print_comment(grade):
    # NOTE `=` is for assignment.  We use it when we want to
    # tell python to make a variable mean something. For example:
    # a = "some_name" basically means that when we call a, it would
    # return the string "some_name".

    # What you want to use here is `==` which is the equality operator.
    # This checks whether or thing are equal.
    if grade == 'A':
        print("COMMENT:            Very Good")
    elif grade == 'B':
        print("COMMENT:            Good")
    elif grade == 'C':
        print("COMMENT:            Satisfactory")
    elif grade == 'D':
        print("COMMENT:            Need Improvement")
    elif grade == 'F':
        print("COMMENT:            Poor")


# NOTE 1: you need to assign the function results to a
# variable (or variables), otherwise, the result or return value
# will go nowhere and you can't use it
tavge, id, exam = read_test_scores()
print "TEST AVERAGE IS:    " + str(tavge)

# NOTE 2: variable names do not have to be the same as
# the name in their respective functions.  Here, you can see
# that it will still run even if I changed the variable
# name final_score to my_variable.  Although, of course, using
# final_score would still work.

# NOTE 3: the final_score function requires 2 inputs,
# namely tavge and exam.  This basically means that you have to feed
# it with these 2 values for it to work.  I took the
# tavge and exam variables as the results from your read_test_scores
# function
my_variable = compute_final_score(tavge, exam)
print("FINAL SCORE IS:     " + str(my_variable))
grade = get_letter_grade(my_variable)
print("LETTER GRADE IS:     " + str(grade))
print_comment(grade)


# FINAL NOTE: I haven't commented regarding coding style etc (like say
# for instance, there are best practices regarding variable names
# within functions, that is, if they should be similar to variable names
# outside the function), but regardless, the code is a good start.  I
# would also advise you to try to narrow down your question first
# before posting.  This can be done by running your code, and searching
# the internet for the particular erro messages, and if you're still stuck,
# ask here on stackoverflow.
```

Comment: it's running nicely now but any idea as to why it isn't accurately calculating the test average and final score? I entered exam score 90 and test scores 80, 65, 70, 86, 97.5, 70, and 84.5. It calculates test average as 78 and final score as 85.2 but it should be 79 and 85.6

Comment: It's probably due to integer division.  What this means, is that when python divides an integer with another integer, the result gets rounded down. For example, 10/6 would return 1 instead of 1.666... . The solution is to make sure that you are dividing with or by a float (or a number with a decimal point) so that it will also return a float. So in this instance, if we divide 10.0/6, 10/6.0, or 10.0/6.0 you will get the desired 1.666... I'll update the code in a while, but I'll just add a decimal to point to the 7 divisor you used.

Comment: gotcha, thanks a lot for the help and advice

Answer (score 0):

there are many errors in your code, some of them are in the comment, but the most critical part is that you use global and local variables incorrectly

here is and example of fixing your code using the correct way to use global variables.

https://repl.it/repls/SorrowfulOddballSongbird

```
tavge = 0
exam = 0
sid = 0
final_score = 0
grade = ''

def read_test_scores() :

    global sid
    print("ENTER STUDENT ID: ")
    sid = int(input())

    global exam
    print("ENTER EXAM SCORE: ")
    exam = int(input())

    print("ENTER ALL TEST SCORES: ")
    score1 = int(input())
    score2 = int(input())
    score3 = int(input())
    score4 = int(input())
    score5 = int(input())
    score6 = int(input())
    score7 = int(input())

    total = (score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 + score6 + score7)

    global tavge
    tavge = total/7
    #return tavge

def compute_final_score() :
    global final_score
    final_score = 0.4 * tavge + 0.6 * exam
    #return final_score

def get_letter_grade() :
    global grade
    if 90 <= final_score <= 100:
        grade = 'A'
    elif 80 <= final_score <= 89:
        grade = 'B'
    elif 70 <= final_score <= 79:
        grade = 'C'
    elif 60 <= final_score <= 69:
        grade = 'D'
    else:
        grade = 'F'
    #return grade

def print_comment() :
    if grade == 'A':
        print("COMMENT:            Very Good")
    elif grade == 'B':
        print ("COMMENT:            Good")
    elif grade == 'C':
        print ("COMMENT:            Satisfactory")
    elif grade == 'D':
        print ("COMMENT:            Need Improvement")
    elif grade == 'F':
        print ("COMMENT:            Poor")

read_test_scores()
print ("TEST AVERAGE IS:    " + str(tavge))
compute_final_score()
print ("FINAL SCORE IS:     " + str(final_score))
get_letter_grade()
print ("LETTER GRADE IS:     " + str(grade))
print_comment()
```

but you should consider using parameters instead using globals

Answer (score 0):

As several people have mentioned you need to use == for comparison, you also are missing a colon after one of your if/else.

This is my take on your code. Keep in mind that this doesn't have and tests to make sure someone is actually entering in a number for a test score instead of text

"sum" is also the name of a built in function to Python, which sums up anything you provide it.

```
def read_test_scores():
    scores = []
    num_tests = 7
    print("ENTER ALL TEST SCORES: ")
    for i in range(num_tests):
        score = input("Test " + str(i + 1) + ":")
        scores.append(int(score))    

    return sum(scores) / num_tests    


def compute_final_score(average, exam_score):
    score = 0.4 * average + 0.6 * exam_score
    return score    


def get_letter_grade(finalized_score):
    if 90 <= finalized_score <= 100:
        letter_grade = 'A'
    elif 80 <= finalized_score <= 89:
        letter_grade = 'B'
    elif 70 <= finalized_score <= 79:
        letter_grade = 'C'
    elif 60 <= finalized_score <= 69:
        letter_grade = 'D'
    else:
        letter_grade = 'F'
    return letter_grade    


def print_comment(letter_grade):    
    if letter_grade == 'A':
        print("COMMENT:            Very Good")
    elif letter_grade == 'B':
        print("COMMENT:            Good")
    elif letter_grade == 'C':
        print("COMMENT:            Satisfactory")
    elif letter_grade == 'D':
        print("COMMENT:            Need Improvement")
    elif letter_grade == 'F':
        print("COMMENT:            Poor")    


def get_student_id():
    print("ENTER STUDENT ID: ")
    identity = int(input())
    return identity    


def get_exam_score():
    print("ENTER EXAM SCORE: ")
    exam_score = int(input())
    return exam_score    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    student_id = get_student_id()
    exam = get_exam_score()
    tavge = read_test_scores()
    print("TEST AVERAGE IS:    " + str(tavge))
    final_score = compute_final_score(tavge, exam)
    print("FINAL SCORE IS:     " + str(final_score))
    grade = get_letter_grade(final_score)
    print("LETTER GRADE IS:     " + str(grade))
    print_comment(grade)
```